# How to fix velcro wrist strap on boxing gloves?

Tags: boxing, equipment, training

I have a pair of Muay kickboxing gloves and after about 1 year of using them, the velcro wrap doesn't hold anymore. The only solution is can think of is tying them up with sports tape, but I sometimes need to take them off during training and then I have to tie them up again, which is inconvenient.
Can I just sew an extra laying of velcro on the glove, over the old one? Will that work?

Comment: So there's no tear in the glove? It's just that the velcro has worn so much that it no longer works?

Comment: Exactly, there's almost no grip. After a couple of hard shots, the band comes off and sometimes scratches the other guy's face, so it's something I want to fix fast, without having to buy new gloves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is going to a shoe repair shop and have them replace the velcro straps on my gloves, really happy with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest that you first check the side of velcro on your gloves that has the little hooks on it. Sometimes you can get a buildup of lint or other material that prevents it from grabbing on to the velvet/felt side. If this is the case you can tease out the lint and it should start grabbing better.

If the wrap still won't hold then sewing a new layer of velcro on should work, just test to see which side is failing so that you don't double your sewing for no reason.